# Python / double for-loop iteration over dictionary and json file not working properly

Tags: python, for-loop

i wrote an little algorithm that iterates over a dictionary and then over a json file with the goal to replace specific keys.

I have three items in the dictionary that should be replaced. The problem is that the function only replaces the first entry from the dictionary and not the other ones but the foor loop is iterated three times, like it should.

I think its a logical error but i dont find it.

```
class Replacer:
    def __init__(self, form_json_path: str, replace_dict: dict):
        self.file_read = open (f'{form_json_path}', 'r')
        self.file_path = form_json_path
        self.replace_dict = replace_dict

    def replace_keys(self):
        replaced_json = ''

        for before, after in self.replace_dict.items():
            search_phrase = f'"key":"{before}"'
            additional_search_phrase = f'"key": "{before}"'

            for line in self.file_read:
                if (search_phrase in line or additional_search_phrase in line):
                    replaced_json_line = line.replace(f'{before}', f'{after}')
                    replaced_json += replaced_json_line
                else:
                    replaced_json += line

        print(replaced_json)
        self.file_read.close()


keys_to_replace = {
    "antragsumfang_Panel": "antragsumfang_PanelREPLACED",
    "antragsumfangHinweis_HTMLElement": "antragsumfangHinweis_HTMLElementREPLACED",
    "antragsumfangHinweisZwei_HTMLElement": "antragsumfangHinweisZwei_HTMLElementREPLACED"
}

f = Replacer('t.json', keys_to_replace)
f.replace_keys()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. Do you want to rename keys in the JSON file according to the dictionary?

Comment: This is not how you process JSON. Even if this problem is solved, you'll have many more problems, like escaping characters properly. Don't go this way. Parse the JSON, and perform your manipulations on the data structure, and finally transform it back to JSON (if that's needed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lies in the inner loop. Files objects do not automatically go back to the beginning of the file when they reach the end. The first time, it iterates over the lines as it should but the second and third times it does nothing because it is already at the end.
To fix this add `self.file_read.seek(0)` after the inner loop to go back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I already had restructured the algorithm and it also worked but it didnt looked so good like the first version. So i just added your line to the end of the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

`for line in self.read(file)` will only iterate the file once. So at the second iteration of the outer loop, the file will not be iterated again. Moreover, if it would, you would execute `replaced_json +=`  more times than you have lines in your input.

But more importantly, this is not how you should work with JSON. It is bad practice to replace strings in JSON hoping that the result will still be valid JSON. It will fail when you have characters that need escaping, like backslashes or quotes, not to mention the other JSON encoding rules.

You really should be using the `json` module for this:

```
import json

class Replacer:
    def __init__(self, form_json_path: str, replace_dict: dict):
        with open(form_json_path, 'r') as f:
            self.data = json.load(f)
        self.file_path = form_json_path
        self.replace_dict = replace_dict

    def replace_keys(self):
        def transform(key, val):
            return self.replace_dict.get(val, val) if key == "key" else val

        def walk(data):  # recursive traversal through nested data structure
            if isinstance(data, dict):
                return {
                    key: walk(transform(key, val))
                    for key, val in data.items()
                }
            if isinstance(data, list):
                return list(map(walk, data))
            return data

        result = walk(self.data)
        print(result)
        

keys_to_replace = {
    "a": "aa",
    "b": "bb",
    "c": "cc"
}

f = Replacer('t.json', keys_to_replace)
f.replace_keys()
```